# Which application pool does an application use by default

Tags: iis, application-pool

If I create a number of application pools, and then create an application but don't specify which application pool it should run in, which one does it use?

Is it random? Does it always take the first one? Something else?

Comment: It really depends on how to create that application. IIS Manager or PowerShell cmdlets have different default values (and rules to determine those).

Comment: Hi, is there any recent progress on this issue? Has this issue been resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default application pool used is defined in applicationHost.config.

Both the [sites element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/) and the [site element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/) have a child element named applicationDefaults. This has an optional attribute named "applicationPool".

If the [application element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/) doesn't have it's optional "applicationPool" element set, it takes it from site.applicationDefaults, and then from sites.applicationDefaults. If none are set the application will fail to run.

Answer (score 2):

When you do not specify an existing application pool when you create the site, the site will create a new application pool with the same name as the site.
[image: image1]

If you use IIS Manager and add an application to your website, by default the application uses the application pool you selected when the website was created.
[image: image2]

However, if you use appcmd.exe or PowerShell to add applications, the situation is different from using IIS Manager. By default, applications use the DefaultAppPool instead of random.

Using appcmd.exe:

```
appcmd add app/site.name:test/path:/blig/physicalPath:C:\inetpub\app1 ---Create app1

appcmd list app "test/app1" ---Verify the Apppool used by app1 by default
```

[image: image3]

Using PowerShell:

```
New-Item 'IIS:\Sites\test\app2' -physicalPath C:\inetpub\app2 -type Application
```

[image: image4]